# DRM/KMS disable connector and crtc

Tags: android, linux, drm

I have Android on my device.
I'm drawing pictures before Android finish his loading.
I have issue with high DDR usage(average frequency too high),
checked by cat /sys/kernel/debug/clk/measure_only_mccc_clk/clk_measure

I found temporary solution - release drm resources before Andoid. But it is not good for me as I have black screen gap between my pictures and Android displaying.

If I move releasing of resources on time after Android I receiving again my problem with high DDR freq.

I checked state of /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/state and find out the difference between success work of DDR and unsuccess.

so difference:

```
connector[168]: shared-disp-1
    crtc=(null)
```

and

```
connector[168]: shared-disp-1
    crtc=crtc-6
```

and for crtc's

```
crtc[170]: crtc-6
    enable=0
    active=0
    planes_changed=1
    mode_changed=1
    active_changed=1
```

and

```
crtc[170]: crtc-6
    enable=1
    active=1
    planes_changed=1
    mode_changed=0
    active_changed=0
```

So questions is:

1. Where can I read about work with drm in userspace?
2. How to disable connector and crtc?

Answer (score 0):

So I finded the way how to disable CRTC in my case
It's just need to call in the end of my program

```
bufferId = 0;
x, y = 0;
arrayOfConnectors = nullptr;
numberOfConnectors = 0;
mode = nullptr;
drmModeSetCrtc(fd, crtcId, bufferId, x, y, arrayOfConnectors, numberOfConnectors, mode);
```